# Iterative Post request in Postman

Tags: rest, post, postman

I need help for doing Post request repeatedly in Postman with different bodies. Example given below, where company name must be changed. It would be better to read company names from a document or may be from an array in script. Please advice how can I do it?

```
{
  "d": "{{company}}"
}
```

I found somethin like that, but I am getting error: `(There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined)`

Pre-request Script:

```
if(!companies){
    companies = ["111",
                 "222",
                 "333"];
}

var currentCompany = companies.shift();
pm.enviroment.set("company",currentCompany);
pm.enviroment.set("companies", companies);
```

Tests:

```
var companies = pm.enviroment.get("companies");


if(companies && companies.length > 0){
    postman.setNextRequest("my url");
} else {
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```

Comment: You can use pre-request script in Postman, search for it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have edited question, please check what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple but small mistakes:

1. the set environment function is misspelled: please use `pm.environment.set`(right) instead of `pm.enviroment.set`(false)
2. you have to load the companies var from the environments before. Add `var companies = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("companies"));` to the first line of your pre rquest script.
3. Please make sure that you are saving string values to the environment vars. Use `JSON.stringify(myObject)` e.g. `pm.environment.set("company", JSON.stringify(currentCompany));` and analogue JSON.parse(myStringVar) for loading variables in `var companies = JSON.parse(pm.enviroment.get("companies"));`
4. (Maye also a problem) Please make sure, there is a enviroment chosen in Postman, postman-runner and newman. If there is no environment set, you can get errors: [image]

Comment: @SamirAmanov If my posting was helpful, I would be glad if you accept it as the correct answer.